# How to find a Java constant from its value?

Tags: java, eclipse, constants

I want to get an objet in a Request attribute, and I found this attribute by retro-ingeneering.
But, I can't find the constant that was used to name this attribute.
How can I find this constant from its value ?

I'm using Eclipse, and I don't have the source code of all the JARs I use.

Thank you !

Comment: You can't find a constant's name by its value.

Comment: Too broad to answer, you would need to use a sort of bytecode analizer or library like  ASM, Byte buddy, javassist, etc ... and take into account that you could find more than one constant (I guess you want to find a static final value) with the same value... or none...

Comment: Eclise has access to all the classes, and to all the constants, so it could make a simple CONSTANT.equals("myvalue") for all the String constants of the workspace.  A plugin that makes it may exist.

Comment: By request do you mean HttpServletRequest from java EE? You could also say what value you have, it might be easier to point where this value is defined as constant

Comment: Indeed, by request I mean HttpServletRequest from java EE. But that's just an example.
"You could also say what value you have, it might be easier to point where this value is defined as constant" ==> That is exactly the point of my question : I don't know where this Constant is defined (if it is : some people can make ugly code), and I want to find it.